# slick 3 two leftJoin query result to classes mapping

Tags: tuples, left-join, slick-3.0

Current question is relative with [next one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217252/slick-3-composite-list-insert-in-transaction/36271481#36271481), but now I need to read the data from database instead of insert.

I have next three case classes:

```
case class A (id: Long, bList: List[B])
case class B (id: Long, aId: cList: List[C])
case class C (id: Long, bId: Long)
```

And query with two `leftJoin` functions and `incomingAId` for filtering aTable results:

```
  val query = (for {
    ((aResult,bResult),cResult) <- aTable.filter(_.id === incomigAId)
      .joinLeft(bTable).on(_.id === _.aId)
      .joinLeft(cTable).on(_._2.map(_.id) === _.bId)
  } yield ((aResult,bResult),cResult)).result.transactionally
```

Next query works and the result looks valid, but isn't easy to handle it to the case classes. Also, `executionResult` has `Seq[Nothing]` type and process of mapping requires something like that:

```
database.run(query).map{ executionResult =>
  executionResult.map { vectorElement: [Tuple2[Tuple2[A, Option[B]], Option[C]]]
     ...
  }
}
```

Is there any proper way to prevent Seq[Nothing] (changes in query)?
Or if the query result type is fine, could you please share solution how to map it to the case classes above?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm using next solution, but I suppose that some part of code can be optimized (e.g. `groupBy` replacing with something else).

```
     execute(query).mapTo[Vector[((A, Option[B]), Option[C])]]
        .flatMap { insideFuture =>
          insideFuture.groupBy(_._1._1).mapValues { values =>
            //scala groupBy losts ordering
            val orderedB = values.groupBy(_._1._2).toSeq.sortBy(_._1.map(_.id)).toMap
            orderedB.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
          }.headOption match {
            case Some(data) => Future.successful {

              data._1.copy(bList = data._2.map {
                case (Some(bElement), optionCElements) =>
                  bElement.copy(cList = optionCElements.toList.flatten)

                case _ =>
                  throw new Exception("Invalid query result. Unable to find B elements")
              }.toList)
            }
            case None => Future.failed(new Exception("Unable to find A with next id " + incomigAId))
          }
        }
    }
```